# Jquery/javascript copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard, zclip

I'm using http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/#usage to copy some text to the clipboard and that code is working just fine.  It uses flash to create a crossbrowser solution and it is based on [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard), which seems to be considered to be the best working solution at the moment.

However I would like to have multiple copy to clipboard buttons or links on my page.  Here is an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/TB23d/

This code works, it copies the text of the coupon code to the clipboard and opens up a new page with the correct link.  How can I use that code on other links without having to duplicate it for each and every link / id.

Using just the class

```
$(function() {
$('.copy').zclip({
    path: 'http://shopsheep.com/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: $(this).text(),
    afterCopy: function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    }
});
```

});

doesn't work: as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/EAZYW/
if you remove the afterCopy function you'll see that $(this).text() will return the whole page instead of just the text between the link tag.

doing something like this

```
$(function() {
$('a.copy', this).zclip({
    path: 'http://shopsheep.com/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: $('a.copy', this).text(),

});
```

});

slightly improves upon it but returns all text between the link tag as you can see here.
http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/hAh3j/

Comment: I’m voting to close and delete this question because the code on which it is based no longer exists. I cannot delete my own answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: This no longer works but I cannot delete the post

This seems to work - someone might be able to make it more elegant

http://jsfiddle.net/5nLw6/7/

```
$(function() {
    $('.copy').each(function() {
        var linkId = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).zclip({
        path: 'http://shopsheep.com/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $("#"+linkId).text(),
        afterCopy: function() {
            window.open($('#'+linkId).attr('href'));
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it isn't working.  Try forking the jsfiddle with this code and you'll see it's not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/EAZYW/

Comment: I tried zClip within a table, it fails, no Flash is rendered. Going to use ZeroClipboard directly now.

Comment: To whoever decided to downvote a two year old post without leaving a comment... Thanks. Love the fly-by downvotes.

Comment: @Jota This is a NINE YEAR OLD post. Things have changed. The SWF is no longer there and if it were, it would likely be blocked. Instead of voiting down on a NINE YEAR OLD POST, just post a comment saying this no longer works

Answer (score 2):

I actually discovered that using ZeroClipboard directly is just as easy, I just added this code in case someone wants a solution without using zclip.

```
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://shopsheep.com/js/ZeroClipboard.swf');
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".copy").each(function(i) {
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        var myTextToCopy = $(this).text();
        var myTextUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        clip.setText(myTextToCopy);
        clip.addEventListener('complete', function(client, text) {
            window.open(myTextUrl);
        });
        clip.glue($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/JxMbd/

Answer (score 0):

This is what we follow in Oodles Technologies.

To use zero copy to clipboard you need two files
1 . ZeroClipboard.js
2 .ZeroClipboard.swf
both file can be download from here

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src =”../ZeroClipboard.js”></script>
    <script >
     // configure ZeroClipboard first
     ZeroClipboard.config( { moviePath : /path/swffile/ZeroClipboard.swf } );

     // initialize constructor
    var client = new ZeroClipboard($(“#elementid”));

    /* elementid is the element on which click , the data will copy  to clipboard. you can also pass multiple elements, it use jquery selector */
        </script>
<body>
<input type=”text”  id =”targetid”></button>
<button  id =”elementid” data-clipboard-text ='data for copy’ >copy</button>
</body>
</head>
<html>
```

ZeroClipboard automatically copy the value of  data-clipboard-text attribute when event accur on element pass to ZeroClipboard's constructor

Answer (score 0):

Light weight jQuery solution... re-use class to copy text from any element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.copytoclipboard', function(e) {
  if($("#holdtext").length < 1)
    $("body").append('<textarea id="holdtext" style="height:0;width:0;border:0;outline:0;resize:none;"></textarea>');
  $("#holdtext").val($(this).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
});
```